# How to add object to array in constructor

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, oop, constructor

I am programming in JavaScript and I created an array called users and a constructor for the user object. Everytime a new object is created I want to add it to the array.

```
var users = [];


function user(username, password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    users[users.length-1] = this;
};

var joe = new user('Joe', "joe100");
```

The way above doesn't seem to work. How can I add an object to an array in the constructor?

Comment: Just get rid of the `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"users" is an empty array which means its length is 0 when you hit the constructor. So assigning "this" to length-1 would mean **assigning "this" to the "-1" index**...thats why it is not working....get rid of the -1, or...

**Use the javascript array.push()** function instead to add to your array perhaps

Check out the example on W3Schools site...
[Array#push](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove -1 from your code and it will look like bellow one

```
var users = [];


function user(username, password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    users[users.length] = this;
};

var joe = new user('Joe', "joe100");
```

An HTML Demo code example for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var users = [];


function user(username, password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    users[users.length] = this;
};

var joe = new user('Joe', "joe100"),l = new user('ll', "ll99");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = users[0].username+"   ---  "+users[0].password+"<br/>"+users[1].username+"   ---  "+users[1].password;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think this will help you.